# What proportion of Chinese lending to Africa is interest-free, according to the World Bank?

Tags: china, debt, africa, world-bank

I'm trying to figure out if some figures put out by Johns Hopkins CARI (China-Africa Research Initiative) in a WaPo piece include (or don't) the so-called ["hidden lending"](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2019/07/10/figure-of-the-week-chinas-hidden-lending-in-africa/) that China supposedly has given. According to some researchers who wrote a NBER paper on this:

> Globally, the authors estimate that 50 percent of Chinese foreign lending is not officially recorded by the World Bank’s International Debt Statistics database.

WaPo/CARI [claims](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/02/26/pandemic-has-worsened-africas-debt-crisis-china-other-countries-are-stepping/) that (only) 5% of Chinese loans to Africa are interest-free. What does the World Bank say about this? **What percentage of China's loans to Africa are interest-free, according to the World Bank?**

(I have a good reason to suspect a difference by source on this because e.g. the World Bank's DB [says](https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/african-states-private-debts-three-times-that-owed-china-2022-07-11/) only 12% of Africa's debt it owed to China, but CARI puts that figure at 21%--and I think it's not a typo involved.)

Comment: I see that some CARI researches [also](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/248247/1/sais-cari-bp06.pdf) have written about China's "hidden lending", which doubles my suspicion that they'd have included it.

Comment: https://twitter.com/SaisCari Maybe you could ask individuals related to the research directly on Twitter.

Comment: How do you define 'hidden lending'? If a country (or a private entity of that country) pays to build some infrastructure in some other country and makes the host country pay for using it, does that constitute hidden lending?

Comment: Differing definitions are most often the source for greatly different statistics from different sources that are all credible.